# How to return HTML5 formdata data via ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a working perfect jquery ajax + html5 formdata file plus data submit. But how to get the posted data?

```
var fd = new FormData();
fb.apend(); // values here
```

Then ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: fd,
  //something here
}).done(function(res){
   alert(res); // Pop up with nothing
   console.log(res); //New line in Google chrome console but nothing inside.
});
```

Comment: Depends on what's sent back by the server

Comment: HTTP is stateless, and part of that is that the Response does not necessarily carry information from the Request.  In general that would be entirely wasteful since the client that sent the Request would obviously have the Request information.  If you have `fd` why would it to needlessly consume extra bandwidth (implicitly) or add extra complexity to the communication?

Comment: I need to get the auto-increment (insert_id) id from database. @MattWhipple

Comment: @vzhen then you should be returning a representation of the resource which is effectively entirely different from formdata, check your browser console to see what is returned from the server to make sure its what you're expecting.

Comment: @MattWhipple I figured it out, just need to echo in server side and thanks for you explanation. It cleared me. 
<<client that sent the Request would obviously have the Request information>>